# ASP.Net MVC Defining PageLink Within Model Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am following along with a basic MVC video on Youtube and am seeing an error that the video does not explain. I have a ViewList (shown below) and it is giving the below error. Any help would be appreciated. This may be a simple error since I am new to ASP.Net. The error is being thrown up under the starred PageLinks in the View. Thank you in advance.

Notes: I'm assuming I would have to define PageLinks in my ProductListViewModel code, but the video did not have it structured this way. PagingHelpers is a class in a folder I have labeled 'HtmlHelpers'.

Error: 
'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'PageLinks' and no extension method 'PageLinks' accepting a first argument of type 'HTMLHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
View:

@model OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI.Models.ProductListViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{
<div>
    <h3>@p.Name</h3>
    <h4>@p.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
    @p.Description
</div>
}
<div>
   @Html.**PageLinks**(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x}))
</div>

ProductListViewModel:

using OnlineShoppingStore.Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI.Models
{
    public class ProductListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable <Product> Products{ get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
}

PagingHelpers (where I define PageLinks):

using OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class PagingHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
                                                 PagingInfo pagingInfo,
                                                 Func<int, string> pageUrl)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i =1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i ++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                {
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                    tag.AddCssClass("btn-primary");
                }
                tag.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");
                result.Append(tag.ToString());
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your view does not know where extension method `PagingLink` is located, so you need to add `using` statement with correct namespace at the top of your view:

```
@using OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
@model OnlineShoppingStore.WebUI.Models.ProductListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}
@* the rest of the code *@
```

Next time you encounter similar error, the hint to resolving the error could be the error message that you see (especially bolded text):

> (are you **missing a using directive** or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Great, thank you! I new it was something simple like that.